# Balls and Bins Variant Unique Maximum Number of Balls in a Bin

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, balls-in-bins

Suppose there are $m$ balls and $n$ bins where $m \geq n$. The $m$ balls are thrown into the $n$ bins uniformly at random. At the end of each round, all bins with less than the maximum number of balls is removed. Let the remaining number of bins be $n_1$. The process is repeated with $m$ balls and $n_1$ bins, and so on. The question is, what is the expected number of rounds necessary until one bin remains?

One can get a weak bound of $\lg n$ rounds by using the well-known result for expected number of empty bins: $n/e$. But I'm hoping for a tighter bound.

Has anyone ever seen this question before perhaps named differently? Intuitively, this is the *opposite* of what we want with balls and bins (because that's used most often in load balancing), but I don't know a better name to ask this question under.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, if $n|m$, and every bin winds up with the same number of balls, do you keep all $n$ bins to the next round?

Comment: Yes, if all bins end up with the same number of balls, you keep all the bins.